# [UITableViewCellContentView af_cancelImageRequest]: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, alamofire, alamofireimage

I need some help. I use AlamofireImage UIImageView extension to load some icons inside UITableView.
My project use some third party library written in Objective-C.

Code:

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

   func setData(provider: ServiceProvider) {
       name.text = provider.name
       let url = NSURL(string: provider.logoUrl)!
       self.logo.af_setImageWithURL(url)
   }

   override func prepareForReuse() {
       super.prepareForReuse()

       logo.af_cancelImageRequest()
       logo.layer.removeAllAnimations()
       logo.image = nil
   }
}
```

Error:

```
    -[UITableViewCellContentView af_cancelImageRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x787ea430
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView af_cancelImageRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x787ea430'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x02eb1494 exceptionPreprocess + 180
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x03d6ee02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2 CoreFoundation 0x02ebb253 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3 CoreFoundation 0x02df089d ___forwarding_ + 1037
4 CoreFoundation 0x02df046e CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5 AlamofireImage 0x005d324c _TFE14AlamofireImageCSo11UIImageView25af_setImageWithURLRequestfTP9Alamofire21URLRequestConvertible_16placeholderImageGSqCSo7UIImage_6filterGSqPS_11ImageFilter__8progressGSqFT9bytesReadVs5Int6414totalBytesReadS5_24totalExpectedBytesToReadS5__T__13progressQueuePSo17OS_dispatch_queue_15imageTransitionOES_S0_15ImageTransition26runImageTransitionIfCachedSb10completionGSqFGVS1_8ResponseS3_CSo7NSError_T___T + 476
6 AlamofireImage 0x005d2f85 TFE14AlamofireImageCSo11UIImageView18af_setImageWithURLfTCSo5NSURL16placeholderImageGSqCSo7UIImage_6filterGSqPS_11ImageFilter__8progressGSqFT9bytesReadVs5Int6414totalBytesReadS4_24totalExpectedBytesToReadS4__T__13progressQueuePSo17OS_dispatch_queue_15imageTransitionOES_S0_15ImageTransition26runImageTransitionIfCachedSb10completionGSqFGV9Alamofire8ResponseS2_CSo7NSError_T___T + 933
```